# Japanese Keyboard: How do you use the symbols on the￥ key?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, keymap, japanese

On a Japanese keyboard I can see that only the ￥ key has more than two Japanese symbols, i.e. ￥ , |, - and sometimes ¬. Which modifier keys (Shift, Alt, Ctrl etc.) do I need to press to get each of them?

All other keys have no more than two Japanese characters on them, so I can just use Shift to distinguish between them.

I tried testing it on Linux, but Mozc ignored the ￥ key altogether and Windows IME is no better. Does anyone know of a way to make Windows or Linux map an actual Japanese keyboard, including the additional keys that Western keyboards don't have (i.e. Yen, ro, Katakana/Hiragana toggle etc.)?

Comment: did you tried pressing it with AltGr?

Comment: I tried it now and both OS's still ignore the key completely. But if Alt Gr is the key that is supposed to work, then I can use this key for my own implementation nonetheless. So, is it definitely the correct one then?